# Shield UI Bar Chart Overlap

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, shieldui

I want to create a bar chart that has two bar charts in it with Shield UI.

When I do that it shows them side by side but I want them to be overlapped. I don't want the total Y axis value. If I use area chart for example, it does that but for the bar chart it doesn't.

For Example like [this](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-aqjCee2CayE/T0YNkkBzgQI/AAAAAAAAAEM/NduVVseA4VM/s1600/Correlation+Bar+Graph+2008+with+bells+and+whistles.PNG)

Is it possible in Shield UI.

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted them previously for a similar request, and this feature will be available in the newest release of the charting library, due in a few days.

In the meantime, you can use some of the stacking options for the chart. For example:
https://demos.shieldui.com/web/bar-chart/negative-stacked